# Create a generic headers field in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `pandas` dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
```

And it gives me something like the following:

```
                       0       1
0                 123455       1
1                 132750       2
```

I then need to manually add a header row the size of the data, so the data ends up looking like this:

```
                  Field 1      Field 2
0                 123455       1
1                 132750       2
```

To do get the header names I can do:

```
['Field %s' % (n+1) for n in range(df.shape[1])]
```

How would I then add this in as the header? Note that I do not know what the headers are before grabbing the data, and I don't want to "re-load" the dataframe again. I just want to overwrite the headers of "0", "1" with "Field 1", "Field 2". How would this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign to `df.columns`:

```
df.columns = ['Field %s' % (n+1) for n in range(df.shape[1])]
```

With Python 3.6 (PEP 498), you can use f-strings:

```
df.columns = [f'Field {n+1}' for n in range(df.shape[1])]
```

However, note there are possibly clearer ways to achieve what you want:

```
df.columns = np.arange(1, df.shape[1]+1)
df = df.add_prefix('Field ')
```

Comment: very neat, with the `add_prefix`. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it

```
>>> df.rename(columns = {c : 'Field {}'.format(int(c) + 1) for c in range(len(df.columns))})

   Field 1  Field 2
0   123455        1
1   132750        2
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to be the cleanest solution (doesn't need `np`, etc.)

Comment: @David542 to help

Answer (score 0):

You could re-write the index row. For example:

```
>>> df=pd.read_csv('/Users/david/Desktop/hi.csv',header=None)
>>> df
    0  1
0  123455  1
1  132750  2
>>> df.columns = ['Field %s' % (n+1) for n in range(df.shape[1])]
>>> df
   Field 1  Field 2
0   123455        1
1   132750        2
```